Understanding MySQL's Deadlock for un-related tables
I see the following Deadlock in my show engine innodb status's output:
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2024-08-22 09:35:46 0x7f70f2d2d700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 8076065148, ACTIVE 16 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 2, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 331 lock struct(s), heap size 41168, 850 row lock(s), undo log entries 1305
MySQL thread id 3719660, OS thread handle 140126880507648, query id 533501581 10.10.100.10 act Sending data
INSERT INTO JSTOMapping(JourneyStepID,
                                                                  JourneyTargetingTypeID,
                                                                  IsOverridden,
                                                                  Status,
                                                                  CreateBy,
                                                                  CreateDateTime)
             (SELECT 309028,
                     JourneyTargetingTypeID,
                     IsOverridden,
                     'A',
                     10005,
                     NOW()
              FROM JSTOMapping
              WHERE JourneyStepID = 308878
                 AND JourneyTargetingTypeID NOT IN
                  (  18 , 19 ) 
                 AND Status = 'A')
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Status = 'A',

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 13385 page no 1257 n bits 216 index UK_JSTOMapping_JStep_JTargetingType of table `act`.`JSTOMapping` trx id 8076065148 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 8076064865, ACTIVE 16 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 2289
mysql tables in use 2, locked 1
354 lock struct(s), heap size 41168, 913 row lock(s), undo log entries 1707
MySQL thread id 3719662, OS thread handle 140123086968576, query id 533501668 10.10.100.10 act Sending data
INSERT INTO JGTargeting(JourneyID,
                                JGTargetingTypeID,
                                Name,
                                Street,
                                CountryCode3,
                                RegionCode3,
                                actCityID,
                                CityName,
                                actMetroID,
                                GooglePlaceId,
                                PostalStartsWith,
                                Latitude,
                                Longitude,
                                Distance,
                                WhiteListed,
                                Status,
                                CreateBy,
                                CreateDateTime)
    (SELECT #{newParentId},
            JGTargetingTypeID,
            Name,
            Street,
            CountryCode3,
            RegionCode3,
            actCityID,
            CityName,
            actMetroID,
            GooglePlaceId,
            PostalStartsWith,
            Latitude,
            Longitude,
            Distance,
            WhiteListed,
            Status,
            #{userId},
            NOW()

     FROM JGTargeting
     WHERE JourneyID = #{parentId}
       AND Status = 'A')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE WhiteListed        = VALUES(WhiteListed),
                        Status             = 'A',
                        LastUpdateBy       = #{userId},
                        LastUpdateDateTime = NOW();

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 13385 page no 1257 n bits 192 index UK_JSTOMapping_JStep_JTargetingType of table `act`.`JSTOMapping` trx id 8076064865 lock_mode X
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 13316 page no 29970 n bits 104 index UniqueGooglePlaceID of table `act`.`JGTargeting` trx id 8076064865 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)

Below are the table structure for the tables involved:
CREATE TABLE `JSTOMapping` (
   `JSTOMappingID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `JourneyStepID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `JourneyTargetingTypeID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `IsOverridden` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
   `Status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
   `CreateBy` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `CreateDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00',
   `LastUpdateBy` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `LastUpdateDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`JSTOMappingID`),
   UNIQUE KEY `UK_JSTOMapping_JStep_JTargetingType` (`JourneyStepID`,`JourneyTargetingTypeID`),
   KEY `FK_JSTOMapping_JourneyStep` (`JourneyStepID`),
   KEY `FK_JSTOMapping_JourneyTargetingType` (`JourneyTargetingTypeID`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK_JSTOMapping_JourneyStep` FOREIGN KEY (`JourneyStepID`) REFERENCES `JourneyStep` (`JourneyStepID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT `FK_JSTOMapping_JourneyTargetingType` FOREIGN KEY (`JourneyTargetingTypeID`) REFERENCES `JourneyTargetingType` (`JourneyTargetingTypeID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2171332 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


 CREATE TABLE `JGTargeting` (
   `JGTargetingID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `JourneyID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `JGTargetingTypeID` int(2) NOT NULL,
   `Name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Street` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
   `CountryCode3` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ISO-3166-1 alpha 3 code',
   `RegionCode3` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ISO-3166-2 subdivision code',
   `AcuityCityID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `CityName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'from the NetAcuityCity Table',
   `GooglePlaceID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `PostalStartsWith` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Latitude` float DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Location for distance calculation',
   `Longitude` float DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Location for distance calculation',
   `Distance` float DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Distance from latitude/longitude location in km',
   `AcuityMetroID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `WhiteListed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1 for whitelist, 0 for blacklist',
   `Status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
   `CreateBy` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `CreateDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00',
   `LastUpdateBy` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `LastUpdateDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`JGTargetingID`),
   UNIQUE KEY `UniqueGooglePlaceID` (`JourneyID`,`GooglePlaceID`),
   KEY `FK_JGTargeting_Journey` (`JourneyID`),
   KEY `FK_JGTargeting_JGTargetingType` (`JGTargetingTypeID`),
   KEY `FK_JGTargeting_NetAcuityCity` (`AcuityCityID`),
   KEY `FK_JGTargeting_NetAcuityMetro` (`AcuityMetroID`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK_JGTargeting_Journey` FOREIGN KEY (`JourneyID`) REFERENCES `Journey` (`JourneyID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT `FK_JGTargeting_JGTargetingType` FOREIGN KEY (`JGTargetingTypeID`) REFERENCES `JGTargetingType` (`JGTargetingTypeID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT `FK_JGTargeting_NetAcuityCity` FOREIGN KEY (`AcuityCityID`) REFERENCES `NetAcuityCity` (`AcuityCityID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT `FK_JGTargeting_NetAcuityMetro` FOREIGN KEY (`AcuityMetroID`) REFERENCES `NetAcuityMetro` (`AcuityMetroID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14640534 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

I don't understand why Transaction 2(T2) is holding the lock for UK_JSTOMapping_JStep_JTargetingType which is the unique key for table in Transaction 1(T1) and these two tables aren't related to each other. I have seen before that in case of deadlocks, the tables are related to each other but in this case, they are not which is weird. I tried searching for information online but couldn't get any relevant details.
Can someone explain here the MySQL internals for this behaviour? MySQL Server version is Percona Server for MySQL 5.7.40-43-log

the query looks stargne, what is the purpose of it exactly, andthe other transaction what does that make

Are any VIEWs involved?  What do ypu hope to get from ON UPDATE CASCADE?  What does JourneyStep look like?

Are there other statements in each transaction (BEGIN...COMMIT)?
